# ¿Qué son los créditos CPU de las instancias de T2 y T3 en AWS?

Tags: aws, ec2

Soy nueva en [aws](/questions/tagged/aws) y he estado leyendo un poco sobre las intancias que se lanzan cuando se crea un proyecto de *elastic beanstalk*. Quiero implementar una intancia que no truene cuando haya una cantidad excesiva de usuarios consumiendo el servicio.

Al principio usaba las `t2.small` y `t2.micro` y funcionan bien con 500 usuarios quizas 1000 pero el estado de las instancias se degradaba a tal punto que el `env` de *beanstalk* se hacía lento o dejaba de tener un estado saludabe a degradado a tal punto de ya no generar el *endpoint*.

La solución con la que di leyendo en internet fue poner reglas de escaldo algo estrictas, que se escalara la instancia al uso de 40% cpu. La instancia de *bd* es de auroa con un tamaño `t3.medium`, pero jamás consideré los créditos de cpu.

**Mis preguntas son:**

- Una vez que la instancia llega aun límite de cpu y los créditos están en 0, después de un rato de inactividad ¿éstos créditos pueden volverse a recuperar en las intancias `t2`?
- ¿Qué son exactamente los créditos de cpu?
- ¿Cuál sería la diferencia de usar una instancia `t2.large` o `t2.small` pero ilimitada a un `t3.small` o `t3.micro`?

Tengo poco presupuesto para una instancia mayor.

Answer (score 4):

Digamos que las instancias T funcionan como los teléfonos públicos antiguos: Tu echabas monedas y el teléfono, según iban pasando los minutos, se iba tragando las monedas. Reemplaza el teléfono público por la instancia T y las monedas por créditos.

Las instancias T consumen créditos por el tiempo que están activas. Si se consumen todos tus créditos, la instancia se apagará. Los créditos se renuevan con el tiempo, aunque creo que también existe la opción de pasar por caja y adquirir créditos bajo demanda.

Yo, tal y como lo veo, las máquinas T tienen 2 usos principales:

- Probar infraestructuras que no requieran mucho tiempo de ejecución
- Ejecutar algoritmos o pruebas ocasionales

Esto último es mi opinión personal, cada uno administra su cuenta de AWS como mejor le parece, que para eso es quien abona los gastos ocasionados a final de mes.

Comment: Entonces para un ambiente ocupacional las instancias t son una opción pero para casos de uso frecuente quizás una instancia como m5a.large podría funcionar más para producción?

Comment: @alelacuriosa eso es. Las M son de propósito general, luego ya que tengas que usar una m5a.large o una más potente dependerá de la carga de trabajo

Comment: si quizas no formule bien la pregunta, pero las intancias M no usan los creditos de cpu?

Comment: @alelacuriosa no, esas se pagan por tiempo de uso

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora si ya quedo mas claro :D

Answer (score 2):

El funcionamiento del tipo “T” es el siguiente (modo ilimitado, que es el modo por defecto):

- Se escoge un tipo de máquina, la cual debe funcionar más o menos
  dentro de una línea base de ocupación de CPU. Por ejemplo para un
  t3.xlarge con 4 vpcus la línea base que se establece es el 40% de la
  CPU.
- Cada hora que el servidor está con la CPU por debajo de 40% se
  acumulan créditos (96€/hora) hasta un máximo de 2.304 $. (los valores
  puede que no sean los actuales)
- Cuando la CPU sube del 40% comienza a consumir los créditos
  acumulados.
- Si la carga sigue alta y se agotan todos los créditos, **no pasa nada,**
  todo seguirá funcionando con la única diferencia de que tendremos que
  pagar por el consumo adicional de CPU que se está produciendo.

El modo “estándar” (deberían llamarlo clásico o legacy, ya que el modo por defecto es el ilimitado) el funcionamiento es el mismo con la diferencia de que cuando se acaban los créditos el uso máximo de CPU vuelve a ser el de la línea base (tope 40% con nuestro ejemplo). Tampoco implica la parada de nada, simplemente todo irá más lento.

Esto es, en ningún caso el procesamiento "para". Si en tu caso ves que tienes problemas de rendimiento continuos, muy probablemente tu carga media es superior a la línea base de la familia "T", por lo que deberían pensar en pasar a una familia "M" (habría que analizar si aplica otra). Una instancia tipo M puede ser más económica que la tipo "T" si estás continuamente superando el límite de la línea base.

Este video de AWS es algo antiguo, pero explica muy bien todo esto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzVpynd_2GM